# My are links not working

Tags: html

So my problem is this when I upload my files to the server the links quit working. They work just fine when I open a html page and click on the links I don't know what's going on with the links. Here are my links I don't see anything wrong with it.

**Html:**

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">
  <img class="back" src="images/back.png" alt="Back">
</a>

<a href="file:///Users/RyanGlass/Desktop/public_html/home.html">
  <img class="home" src="images/Home.png" alt="Home">
</a>

<a href="file:///Users/RyanGlass/Desktop/public_html/links.html">
  <img class="links" src="images/links.png" alt="links">
</a>

<a href="file:///Users/RyanGlass/Desktop/public_html/summary.html">
  <img class="summary" src="images/summary.png" alt="summary">
</a>

<a href="file:///Users/RyanGlass/Desktop/public_html/Index.html">
  <img class="contact" src="images/contact.png" alt="contact">
</a>
```

Comment: Check ur server configuration to allow the redirection or something like that.

Comment: its a school assignment I cant change the server redirection I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server there will not be the path like:

```
<a href="file:///Users/RyanGlass/Desktop/public_html/home.html">
```

So you can/must set relative or absolute paths. On the server you most probably will not have the path `file:///Users/RyanGlass/Desktop/`

Absolute paths have a reference to the root directory so:

```
<a href="/home.html">
```

or

```
<a href="http://your-domain.com/home.html">
```

Or like pointed in the comments you use `relative` paths. Relative paths have the reference to the current directory they are used in. Something like:

```
<a href="home.html">
```

Comment: It is better to have relative paths - more able to move stuff about

Comment: Thank you! I will try that! :)

Comment: @EdHeal thanks for the comment! Used the wrong word, `relative` is what I meant.

Comment: @RyanGlass you're welcome, let us know if it is or if it is not working for you

Comment: @RyanGlass now if you change that then of course it will not work on your computer anymore. To avoid changing the paths on your computer and on the server you could use a virtual server on your computer such as [MAMP for OSX](https://www.mamp.info/en/) or search for WAMP if using Windows

Comment: `<a href="/home.html">` is an absolute path. `<a href="home.html">` would be better

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the relative paths and absolute paths! It really helped point me in the right direction to fixing my problem! :D